# Swift 3: Pass in the indexPath into another Class

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that returns an array of posts, `[Post]`. Inside of the collectionViews cell class (the actual posts), I have a view called `profileSegueContainer`. the isUserInteractionEnabled is of course set to true and I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that runs a function when this view is tapped. This function simply presents another ViewController. I want to be able to pass in the `post.uid` into this ViewController when I tap the `profileSegueContainer`. How do I achieve this? Thank you. The relevant code is below. Any advice will be highly appreciated...

```
class Post: NSObject {

    var author: String?
    var avatar_image_url: String?
    var likes: Int?
    var postImageUrl: String?
    var uid: String?
    var post_id: String?
    var hashtags: [String]?
}

class PostCell: BaseCell {

    var homeController: HomeController?

    lazy var profileSegueContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return view
    }()

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileSegue))
        profileSegueContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

       topBar.addSubview(profileSegueContainer)
    }

    func handleProfileSegue() {
        let userProfileController = UserProfileController()
        let navigationUserProfileController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfileController)
        homeController?.present(navigationUserProfileController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can achive using custom Tap class , Try this code

import UIKit
class customTap: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var objPost : Post! = nil
 }
// USE LIKE : 
let tap = customTap(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileSegue:))
tap.objPost = yourPostDataobject
    profileSegueContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Comment: @Jay Mahta Thanks man. Means a lot. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I have updated my comment. Look at it once.

Comment: I don't see why we'd need to pass anything through the UITapGestureRecognizer. Your PostCell could just have a postId property that's available class wide.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding your problem correctly. You want to pass a value into a new UserProfileController object?

Add a property to your UserProfileController

```
class UserProfileController : UIViewController {
    public var postId : Int!
// more stuff ....
}
```

Then you just access the property after you create your object:

```
func handleProfileSegue(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  let userProfileController = UserProfileController()
    userProfileController.postId = 2345
    // more stuff...
}
```

Let me know if this is what you needed. If not, we'll update our posts.

Comment: unfortunately when I try to print the postId once the UserProfileController loads, it returns a nil

Comment: @Jimmy are you able to print your `postId` in your `setupViews()` method?